# Programatically Linearlayout set background color using attribute

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog builder where i am defining the layout programatically. 
I have a linear layout that I want to set an attribute to so at runtime i can change the color theme of the app. I am getting most things to work but I cant figure out how to do the linear layout since its not defined in xml.

I do have a hex color code hardcoded i, but thats not what i want. Is there a way to set an attribute like ?attr/colorPrimary

```
alertAFFY = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddMakeActivity.this);
            LinearLayout mainLayout = new 
            LinearLayout(AddMakeActivity.this);
            mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LinearLayout layoutTitle = new LinearLayout(AddAlarmActivity.this);
            layoutTitle.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            TextView title = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            title.setPadding(0, 30, 0, 30);



            title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

            title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 24);
            title.setText("Select One");
            layoutTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            layoutTitle.addView(title);


     **//  i need to change the background color to take in ?attr/ **

            layoutTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F8B195"));

            layoutTitle.setMinimumHeight(20);
            mainLayout.addView(layoutTitle);
```

I am trying to access the theme attribute

```
  <style name="Theme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/toolbarColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorDays">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

is there a way to set an attribute to the linear layout background color? I need it to be dynamic so i can change it at runtime. It cant be hardcoded in there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();

getApplicationContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValue, true);

// it's probably a good idea to check if the color wasn't specified as a resource
if (typedValue.resourceId != 0) {
    layoutTitle.setBackgroundResource(typedValue.resourceId);
} else {
    // this should work whether there was a resource id or not
    layoutTitle.setBackgroundColor(typedValue.data);
}
```

Comment: If you use from `Fragment` then you use `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: This accesses the R.attr which is the wrong color and not what i want. This wont chnage with the theme. i want to access the  <style name="Theme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/toolbarColor</item>

Comment: Do you wan't to set style on `LinerLayout` ?

Comment: nevermind i got it. I had to rework it a bit but its working.

Comment: TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
                Resources.Theme theme = getTheme();
                theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorAccent, typedValue, true);
                @ColorInt int color = typedValue.data;
                layoutTitle.setBackgroundColor(color);